# solidity struct unit test

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, struct

I think I am not the only one who has this problem.
I just want to get the names of the variables inside a struct along with typing them.
I have a file that shows the structure of the item. But I do not know how it works.
Its code:

```
const CDTYPE = "ContractDefinition";
const CNAME = "SupplyChain";
const contractDefn = ca =>
  ca.ast.nodes.find(n => n.nodeType === CDTYPE && n.name === CNAME);

const items = (ca) => {
  const item = contractDefn(ca).nodes.find((n) => n.name === "Item");
  if (!item) return null;

  return item
    .members
    .map((t) => ({
      name: t.name,
      nodeType: t.nodeType,
      stateVariable: t.stateVariable,
      type: t.typeName.name,
      mutability: t.typeName.stateMutability,
    }));
};

const isDefined = members => variableName => {
  return members 
    ? members.find((item) => item.name === variableName) 
    : null;
};

const isPayable = members => variableName => {
  if (members === undefined) return false;
  const definition = members.find((item) => item.name === variableName);
  return definition && definition.mutability === "payable";
};

const isType = members => variableName => type => {
  if (members === undefined) return false;
  const definition = members.find((item) => item.name === variableName);
  return definition && definition.type === type;
};

module.exports = {
  items,
  isDefined,
  isPayable,
  isType,
};
```

Comment: It seems it is using the AST generated by the compiler.

Comment: I am a newcomer and I do not know many things. Can you explain more or introduce another way?

Comment: The [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) is created by the compiler when generating the contract's bytecode. It contains details from the compilation like variables, names, types, functions, structs, enums, interfaces, contracts, etc.

Comment: @Ismael Tanks! Do you have any other way?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know another way.